# Custom loop losing its data

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, popup

so I have a custom loop.

Let say there are 5 posts on a single page as below:

Post 1:

```
 Title : Post 1

 Content : Content 1

 Show more button
```

Post 2:

```
 Title : Post 2

 Content : Content 2

 Show more button
```

and so on....

And the code:

```
<div class="title">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<button type="button" class="show_me_open">
  Show more button
</button>
<div id="show_me">
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

So, the title and contents are all different for 5 posts. The popup button (show more button) is from http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/

**Problem**

Let say you don't have the popup layout enabled, and use some other ways to show it. Then the title and contents match the original title and content (example below).

However if the title and contents are shown by the popup (show more button), then it only shows the first post's title and content (example below).

**1. Without popup:**

Post 1:

```
 Title : post 1
 Content: content 1
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 1
        Content: content 1
```

Post 2:

```
 Title : post 2
 Content: content 2
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 2
        Content: content 2
```

Post 3:

```
 Title : post 3
 Content: content 3
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 3
        Content: content 3
```

**With the popup enabled:**

Post 1:

```
 Title : post 1
 Content: content 1
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 1
        Content: content 1
```

Post 2:

```
 Title : post 2
 Content: content 2
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 1
        Content: content 1
```

Post 3:

```
 Title : post 3
 Content: content 3
 Show more button:  
        Title : post 1
        Content: content 1
```

I am not sure why it is doing it, but any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Js code is pretty simple:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#show_me').popup();                  
    });
```

**EDIT 2**

It was pointed out to me that one ID was used for all other posts and it was only pulling the first one.

So, I am adding `post_id` to the button and it will only trigger the div with the same `post_id`.

```
 <?php echo '<button type="button" class="show_me_open" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>
    <i class="material-icons royal_setting">settings</i>
<?php echo '</button>';?>

<?php echo '<div class="show_me" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>                     
    <?php the_title(); ?>                       
<?php echo '</div>';?>
```

Now for the jQuery, how can I change it so that only the same `post_id` with the class of `show_me` will be targeted?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your jQuery code

Comment: I added the jQuery code. Thank you.

Comment: and that's what is the most bizarre about this. The jquery simple opens the popup.

Comment: Quite sure this is not going to fix anything, yet change jQuery to   `$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('.show_me').popup();                  
    });`

Comment: can you post `the_title()` content in your question

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say that it is `id`. Maybe what if I include the jquery within the div by `onclick`?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle showing the behaviour? Its difficult to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emily, I think the problem is only related to your popup id "show_me".

As you mentioned above **show_me** is a **div** element for **post 1**. Similarly you have to give different ids to each post like for **post 2** give **show_me_2** and so on and after that in your document.ready initialize all popup elements.

```
$('#show_me_1').popup();  
$('#show_me_2').popup();  
$('#show_me_3').popup();  
$('#show_me_4').popup();  
$('#show_me_5').popup();
```

**EDIT-4 Solution**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.show_me').popup(); //it was #show_me                    
    }); 
</script>
<?php echo '<button type="button" class="show_me_'. esc_attr( $post->id ) .'_open">' ;?>
    Show me open
<?php echo '</button>';?>

<?php echo '<div id="show_me_'. esc_attr( $post->id ) .'" class="show_me">' ;?>                     
    <?php the_title(); ?>                       
<?php echo '</div>';?>
```

I added id to div element and add "$post->id" with it. May be this may can solve your issue.

Comment: Alternate may work, Just put class instead of id then you don't need to initialize all popup. You just have to type $(".popupclass").popup()

Comment: I see, That makes sense, I think I understand the issue. =) Thank you Eshu!

Comment: So, I added the `EDIT 2` section. Could you be able to help me targeting a specific `post_id` in jQuery?

Comment: @Emily can you put simple HTML structure of EDIT-2. I am not able to figure out that data-post_id concept.

Comment: Please before doing anything just comment your old js and use this statement "$('.show_me').popup();"

Comment: So, I added "Edit 4" section.  =)